# Lost all my images

Tags: images

I connected my phone to laptop via usb. Since my phone storage was almost full so I cut some folders and pasted it on my memory card.But when I opened the folders the  images were gone.  I again cut and pasted it on my phone storage. Images are still gone.How can I recover it?

Comment: First, what device and Android version? Did you copy the files to a memory card in the phone or on the computer?

Answer (score -1):

First stop writing to the drives because after deletion data is just forgotten but not deleted.It gets deleted when it gets replaced by another data.
Now 
Connect your mobile in USB memory instead of media device.And then use recuva to scan the drive.

[Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva)

Comment: Mass storage mode needed to use tools like this hasn't been available for several years.